# Поставить галочку на Checkbutton в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! вопрос простой, но на просторах интернета (кроме неработающих способов .select() и .set()) я решений не нашел. Есть GUI на tkinter, все работает, но возникла нужда по нажатию на кнопку- чтобы на одном Checkbutton галочка ВИЗУАЛЬНО проставлялась. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Привязать к Checkbutton переменную (BooleanVar) и через ее значение менять состояние. Ответ написать сейчас не могу, но вот первый попавшийся пример: https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-widgets-example (правда, пример под Python 2, но суть не меняется)

Comment: @insolor там тоже как я понял делается через cb.select(), у меня же данный метод вызывает ошибку AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Поменяйте эту строку на `self.var.set(True)`.

Comment: @insolor работает! спасибо!

Comment: а где код ? или

Comment: @Александр, вчера оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная идея: привязываем к объекту `Checkbutton` переменную tkinter (`BooleanVar`), и после этого изменяя состояние привязанной переменной меняем состояние и `Checkbutton`:

```
var = BooleanVar()
cb = Checkbutton(self, text="Text", variable=var, command=self.onClick)

...

state = var.get()  # Получаем состояние (True - включено, False - выключено)

...

var.set(True)  # Включаем флажок

...    

var.set(False)  # Выключаем флажок
```

Полный рабочий пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

check_var = BooleanVar()

label_state = Label(root, text='Состояние: ' + str(check_var.get()))

check = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст', variable=check_var)

check.pack()
label_state.pack()


def on_change(*args):
    label_state.config(text='Состояние: ' + str(check_var.get()))

check_var.trace('w', on_change)  # Следим за состоянием переменной, при изменении выполняем функцию


Button(root, text='Включить', command=lambda : check_var.set(True)).pack()
Button(root, text='Выключить', command=lambda : check_var.set(False)).pack()

mainloop()
```